# How to animate full width SearchView expand/collapse in action bar?

Tags: android, android-support-library, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I am using the `SearchView` from the `support.v7` library.  I looked at [this post](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2013/01/animating-searchview.html) which  suggests that you can simply animate a search view by setting the `LayoutTransition`

```
LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(searchBarId);
//Give the Linearlayout a transition animation.
searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

However the above does not work for me.  The search view also seems to only fill part of the screen width in landscape [image: As shown here].  I would like for it fill_parent

I was trying to solve both of these problems by creating a simple animation but failed at `searchView.getLayoutParams();` because it seems to always return null.

The end goal is to have a SearchView in the action bar that expands/collapses smoothly and takes up the width of the screen width in landscape.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Here is the search view setup that I currently have:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        //Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        //Returns null
        //searchView.getLayoutParams();
        return true;
    }
```

And menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
      <item android:id="@+id/search"
            android:title="Search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Updated to include menu xml.

Answer (score 0):

Do in oncreateoptions:

```
MenuItem searchitem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
SearchView search= (SearchView) searchitem.getActionView();
ActionBar.LayoutParams p= new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATch_parent, same here)
search.setLayoutParams(p);
searchitem.expandActionView();
```

Comment: This uses android.app.ActionBar as mentioned in my post I am using the  support v7 library.  Also this does not seem to work for me. I used the support version of your answer.  Have you tested it in landscape orientation?  The expanded search view still isn't taking up the entire width for me in landscape.

Comment: Any reason not to use ActionBar ?

Comment: Yeah I am not using the android.app.Activity so I don't have access to the regular action bar.  I am using the support library for backwards compatibility of some features.